# Internet connection lost after creating network bonds, but restored after rebooing in "emergency mode" on a RHEL7

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, network-interface, bonding

I am a noob at networking, please forgive me if my terminology is not technically correct. I am facing a weird problem with internet connectivity on a RHEL 7 machine after creating network bonds.

**tl;dr:** 
I created 2 bonds in the following manner on a baremetal loaded with RHEL7 that broke my internet connectivity and the machine become public IP is not longer accessible:
bond0 => master, eth0 & eth2 => slaves
bond1 => master, eth1 & eth3 => slaves

1. Restarting the network does not restore connectivity
2. Rebooting the machine does not restore connectivity.
3. Now here's the weird part. If i boot the machine in **emergency mode** (I do that by adding an invalid entry in fstab and rebooting) and than simply reboot back to normal mode, everything's working again! - the internet connection, the public IP.

Can anyone help me understand what makes emergency mode fix the internet connectivity?
And how can i address the problem without monkeying around the emergency mode?

Thanks! Appreciate any inputs.
*PS: I am not posting the contents of the ifcfg-* files to keep the post short.If its needed i can*

**EDIT1**
I narrowed down to problem to the fact that I dont really need to go into emergency mode anymore.
Doing a `service network restart`, I lose internet connectivity.
Doing a `reboot` restores internet connectivity

Comment: You do know that you have to bond on *both* sides? I.e., on the other machine that your LAN is connected to, too? If you are just creating a bond on your RHEL7 machine, of course you'll loose internet connection. Very likely the emergency mode ignored your changes, so you are back to non-bonding mode, so it works again.

Comment: @dirkt thanks for looking at this. I don't completely understand what you mean by both sides. I have 4 Ethernet NICs and i am bonding 2 each into bond0 and bond1 each (using mode4). Then i tried to say ping google.com and it responds with `From lon02qkr001ccz087.ccz087.lon02.ibm.com (10.164.199.115) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's how bonding works. Assume you have two machines A and B, each with two ethernet interfaces. You connect those in pairs by one cable each, like this:

```
+----------+      +----------+     
|     eth0 |------| eth0     |
| A        |      |        B |
|     eth1 |------| eth1     |
+----------+      +----------+
```

Then you can bond the pairs **both** on machine A and machine B, and make them look like a single interface, and a single connection:

```
+----------+      +----------+     
|          |      |          |
| A  bond0 |======| bond0  B |
|          |      |          |
+----------+      +----------+
```

So when A sends packets to B, they go into bond0, then may go through either eth0 or eth1, and the bonding on B makes it looks like they come out of bond0. This way you can either double the bandwidth, or provide against failure of one connection.

Here are things that don't work with bonding:

- Bonding only on A, but not bonding on B and leaving eth0 and eth1 separate
- Bonding on A, and the connecting eth0 and eth1 to two different machines
- Bonding on A, connecting them to different DSL-routers etc., and then hope you get double speed to the internet, or a failsafe connection to the internet.

I don't know what your goal is, and you didn't say. But having ethernet interfaces on **one** machine, and bonding them pairwise without saying what they are connected to makes no sense at all. So whatever it is you are trying to do, bonding is very likely not the solution.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt. What i posted is only a piece of a bigger networking setup. The bonds that I create come to use with those other pieces. Lets say I have an NICs connected to a router which connects to the internet for the sake of this discussion. What I am about -  is the intermittent connectivity problem. If i restart the network `service network restart`, I lose internet connectivity. If i reboot the machine, internet connection is restored.

Comment: Then please explain the bigger networking setup, and explain what you do on the "router". Or more concretely, what exactly you all involved machines that makes you loose connectivity. The thing is if machine A is using bonding, but machine B isn't, you'll loose connectivity. However you arrive at that state. So this is very likely what happens.